# rails 4 activerecord TypeError nil is not a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, activerecord

It appears a table in sql server is placing `nil` in the select statement. I have no idea how to fix this, and if I switch to any other table, I can easily acquire the first record. Has anyone else dealt with this bug? I took the table apart and built a view. It still does it. I am hesitant to monkey patch this. Ideas? How I am hooking up to sql server:

My model:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'vwStorePromosExtSummaryGlobal'
end
```

My controller:

```
class V1::DealsController < ApplicationController
    def by_mall_id
      deals = Deal.where(mallid: params[:id])
      render json: deals
    end
end

# Use sqlserver as the database for Active Record
gem 'tiny_tds', '~> 0.6.1'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', github: 'arthrex/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.1'
```

When I crack open the exact error in the gem I see:

```
     97:     def serializable_hash(options = nil)
     98:       options ||= {}
     99:
    100:       attribute_names = attributes.keys
    101:       if only = options[:only]
    102:         attribute_names &= Array(only).map(&:to_s)
    103:       elsif except = options[:except]
    104:         attribute_names -= Array(except).map(&:to_s)
    105:       end
    106:
    107:       hash = {}
    108:
 => 109: binding.pry
    110:
    111:       attribute_names.each { |n| hash[n] = read_attribute_for_serialization(n) }
    112:
    113:       Array(options[:methods]).each { |m| hash[m.to_s] = send(m) if respond_to?(m) }
    114:
    115:       serializable_add_includes(options) do |association, records, opts|
    116:         hash[association.to_s] = if records.respond_to?(:to_ary)
    117:           records.to_ary.map { |a| a.serializable_hash(opts) }
    118:         else
    119:           records.serializable_hash(opts)
    120:         end
    121:       end
    122:
    123:       hash
    124:     end

[1] pry(#<Deal>)> p attribute_names.each
#<Enumerator: ["mallid", nil]:each>
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
[2] pry(#<Deal>)> p attribute_names
["mallid", nil]
=> ["mallid", nil]
[3] pry(#<Deal>)>
```

This is my full trace:

```
  [1m[36mSQL (49.6ms)[0m  [1mUSE [pcmenu][0m
Processing by V1::DealsController#by_mall_id as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1066"}
  [1m[35mDeal Load (44.5ms)[0m  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) mallid FROM [StorePromosExtSummaryGlobal] WHERE [StorePromosExtSummaryGlobal].[mallid] = N''1066'' AND (salestypeid = 11
 AND calcendDate > ''09-09-2013''
 AND displayDate < ''09-09-2013''
 AND (promoType is null or promoType = 0)) ORDER BY displayName ASC'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 546ms

TypeError - nil is not a symbol:
  activemodel (4.0.0) lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `block in serializable_hash'
  activemodel (4.0.0) lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `serializable_hash'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/serialization.rb:17:in `serializable_hash'
  activemodel (4.0.0) lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb:99:in `as_json'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:50:in `block in encode'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:81:in `check_for_circular_references'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:49:in `encode'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:34:in `encode'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:16:in `to_json'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:90:in `block in <module:Renderers>'
  active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/action_controller/serialization.rb:48:in `_render_option_json'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:33:in `block in _handle_render_options'
  /Users/chrishough/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb:232:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:30:in `_handle_render_options'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/chrishough/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  app/controllers/v1/deals_controller.rb:6:in `by_mall_id'
  apipie-rails (0.0.22) lib/apipie/dsl_definition.rb:193:in `block in _apipie_define_validators'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:383:in `_run__408012802371174283__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
  apipie-rails (0.0.22) lib/apipie/static_dispatcher.rb:56:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__980017763409925121__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  puma (2.5.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.5.1) lib/puma/server.rb:343:in `process_client'
  puma (2.5.1) lib/puma/server.rb:242:in `block in run'
  puma (2.5.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Have you looked at `Model.columns` (where `Model` is your model of course)? What is the table's schema?

Comment: I did not create the table @muistooshort so I am just querying it directly. Here is what I get by running that command:        @coder=nil,
  @default=nil,
  @limit=4,
  @name="mallid",
  @null=false,
  @precision=nil,
  @primary=false,
  @scale=nil,
  @sql_type="int(4)",
  @sqlserver_options=
   {:table_name=>"vwStorePromosExtSummaryGlobal",
    :numeric_scale=>0,
    :numeric_precision=>10,
    :ordinal_position=>1,
    :length=>4,
    :is_primary=>false,
    :is_identity=>false,
    :database_year=>2012},
  @type=:integer>]
[19] pry(main)>

Comment: Does it really only have one column? Can you get the schema as SQL Server sees it? Adding that stuff to the question will produce more readable results BTW, the formatting options in comments are rather limited.

Comment: yes, I created a view with only one column. right now, we have narrowed it down to possibly the active_model_serializers gem

Comment: just confirmed it is not the gem :(

Comment: Have you looked at `attributes` rather than `attribute_names`? I'm thinking that something somewhere inside ActiveRecord is getting confused and quietly slipping a `nil` into the internal data rather than throwing an exception at the point of confusion.

Comment: @muistooshort right now when I run "p attributes" I get: => {"mallid"=>1066, nil=>nil}

Comment: I guess something somewhere doesn't like your view. I don't know anything about SQL Server or the SQL Server driver. I guess you're stuck tracing through the code to see who builds `attributes`, then maybe you can see where the confusion comes from.

Comment: @muistooshort interesting :( I just posted my controller and model, do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I still believe this is a bug in active record, I was able to get around it with the https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers gem.  This gem overrides to_json eliminated the need for the bug code in active record to be called.

anyone else have a better answer?

Updated Controller:

```
class V1::DealsController < ApplicationController

    def by_mall_id
      deals = Deal.where(mallid: params[:id]).first
      render json: deals, serializer: V1::DealSerializer
    end

end
```

My new DealSerializer:

```
class V1::DealSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :MALLID

    def MALLID
      object.mallid
    end

end
```

Comment: Interfacing Rails with an existing system (i.e. something that wasn't set up specifically for Rails) or using "advanced" database features likes views tends to be a messy business. If this works then I'd go with it and move on to less frustrating problems.

Comment: Definitely seems like an ActiveRecord (or json) bug. I have a postgres view that serializes fine to yaml, but has the same problem you mention here with json. This solution worked great though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your table doesn't have a **primary_key**. You can run a migration like this: (this is rails 5 though)

```
class AddFieldToPosaCode < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  execute 'ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(my_column)'
end
```