# ActiveRecord returns one ghost null column for an id less table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have only 9 columns in a table.

```
duggout=# \d fantasy_selections
             Table "public.fantasy_selections"
     Column      |            Type             | Modifiers
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 user_id         | integer                     |
 match_id        | integer                     |
 player_id       | integer                     |
 points          | integer                     |
 is_captain      | boolean                     |
 is_vice_captain | boolean                     |
 is_star_player  | boolean                     |
 created_at      | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at      | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
    "index_fantasy_selections_on_user_id_and_match_id_and_player_id" UNIQUE, btree (user_id, match_id, player_id)
```

But, when I query the table, I get 10 columns with 1 column having a null key. This creates a problem during JSON serialization. Check the last value in the following hash. It is "nil=>nil". For a new record, I do not see the null column.

In a fresh Rails console:

```
☁  duggout [master] ⚡ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)

> f = FantasySelection.new
 => #<FantasySelection user_id: nil, match_id: nil, player_id: nil, points: nil, is_captain: nil, is_vice_captain: nil, is_star_player: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

> f.attributes
=> {"user_id"=>nil, "match_id"=>nil, "player_id"=>nil, "points"=>nil, "is_captain"=>nil, "is_vice_captain"=>nil, "is_star_player"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil, nil=>nil}

> FantasySelection.selection_of(99,6158).first.attributes
  FantasySelection Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "fantasy_selections".* FROM "fantasy_selections"  WHERE "fantasy_selections"."user_id" = 99 AND "fantasy_selections"."match_id" = 6158 LIMIT 1
 => {"user_id"=>99, "match_id"=>6158, "player_id"=>1, "points"=>100, "is_captain"=>nil, "is_vice_captain"=>nil, "is_star_player"=>nil, "created_at"=>Sun, 25 Jan 2015 11:31:54 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sun, 25 Jan 2015 11:31:54 UTC +00:00, nil=>nil}

> FantasySelection.selection_of(99,6158).first.to_json
     `TypeError: nil is not a symbol`
```

The model:

```
class FantasySelection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :match
  belongs_to :player

  scope :selection_of, ->(user_id, match_id) { where(user_id: user_id, match_id: match_id) }
end
```

Schema.rb for this table:

```
  create_table "fantasy_selections", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "match_id"
    t.integer  "player_id"
    t.integer  "points"
    t.boolean  "is_captain"
    t.boolean  "is_vice_captain"
    t.boolean  "is_star_player"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "fantasy_selections", ["user_id", "match_id", "player_id"], name: "index_fantasy_selections_on_user_id_and_match_id_and_player_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

Note that this table does not have a `id` column. It was created with `id: false` during `create_table` migration.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that `(user_id, match_id, player_id)` isn't a three column PK? Isn't there some magic incantation you need to tell ActiveRecord that it is working with an `id`less table?

Comment: Can you share your `schema.rb` file?

Comment: @DavidKim added the schema.rb file

Comment: @muistooshort no it is not a PK, just a unique index on 3 columns, as evident from the table description from postgres

Comment: You misunderstand. I can see that you just have a three column unique constraint and that everything allows NULL (probably because that's the somewhat bizarre Rails default). But, is it really valid for any of those three columns to be NULL? If not then those three columns are, in fact, a PK even if you don't call it one. And you still aren't doing anything to tell Rails that there's no `id` column in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Would you believe me if I said the nil id had *nothing to do with anything*?

I tried to recreate the error and decided look deeper in the trace.

**Tracing Stack**

It's useful to trace the callstack more so I tried to recreate this error. I went something along the lines of ...

```
TypeError: nil is not a symbol
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activemodel-4.1.5/lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `block in serializable_hash'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activemodel-4.1.5/lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `each'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activemodel-4.1.5/lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `serializable_hash'
```

This suggested to me a problem with the object that you are asking to convert to JSON.

In your example, `FantasySelection.selection_of(99,6158).first.to_json` returns an error, but if in rails console, you save it to an instance:

`a = FantasySelection.selection_of(99,6158).first.to_json`

then `a.to_json` things work fine.

**Explanation?**

While still in your console, try

`FantasySelection.selection_of(99,6158).first.class`

then, try

`FantasySelection.selection_of(99,6158).first.attributes.class`

You will see that you can convert Hash to JSON, but not the first, which is just database result returned in your console.

I suspect this may not solve your problem (I am only addressing the rails console error you pointed to).  I hope this link is useful:
[rails 4 activerecord TypeError nil is not a symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710761/rails-4-activerecord-typeerror-nil-is-not-a-symbol)